# Can't install Hyper-V on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, hyper-v, hypervisor

I don't see Hyper-V at "Windows Futures". I turned on virtualization in BIOS. I also check that my computer is a SLAT capable machine.

Comment: Are you using a 32 or 64-bit install? You can install and configure on a 32 bit but you won't actually be able to use it. Here's some instructions on how to do it: http://www.howtogeek.com/76532/how-to-install-or-enable-hyper-v-virtualization-in-windows-8/

Comment: Also check if you have Win 8.1 PRO version.

Comment: I use 64-bit Windows. And I don't see Hyper-V here http://cdn.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/sshot-82.png

Comment: What's your CPU? Are your Windows 8.x **PRO** ?

Comment: Yeh, guys. Thank you. I use Windows 8.1 for one language.

Comment: hey how did you fix this @user3293277

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

1)Copy paste this code in notepad

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

2) save it as .bat

3) run it as admin

4) restart and check whether HyperV is enabled or not

Answer (score 0):

The following prerequisites are required to successfully run Client Hyper-V on Windows 8.1:

1. Windows 8 Pro or Enterprise 64 bit Operating System
2. 64 bit processor with Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)
3. 4GB system RAM at minimum
4. BIOS-level Hardware Virtualization support

Check out this - http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/11/05/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-8-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Download Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45520) and restart the machine.

Comment: How would this help? Could you provide further explanation? That would greatly improve your answer.